# Code that has to input letters A and B and make then all A's by flipping them doesn't work for all options

Tags: python

I have written a code that inputs a row of A's or B's from the user where they also input how many pancakes in a row the flipper can flip where it outputs how many flips are required to make the row of A's or B's all A's.

If the row of letters can't be flipped evenly the code should output 'This can't be done'.

Example: If the user inputs BBBB with a flipper size of 2 the program would output it took 2 flips.

Flip 1 was from letter 1-2 to it is AABB and flip 2 was from letter 3-4 so it is now AAAA where two flips were needed.

I have written code for this and it does work in most cases but one problem is when I input BBAABB it says that it can't be done with a flipper size of 4 whereas it actually can be done with the first flip being done from letters 1-4 so it is now AABBBB and the second flip being done from letters 3-6 so it is now AAAAAA where it was successful and took 2 flips and I am not sure how I can fix this with my code.

```
while True:
    pancakes = input('Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): ') 
    flipper = int(input('How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? ')) 

    flips, possible = 0, True 
    for row in pancakes.split('A'):
        count, remainder = divmod(len(row), flipper) 
        if remainder != 0:
            possible = False 
            break 
        flips += count 

    if possible: 
      if flips == 1:
        print('It took 1 flip.') #print out how many flips it took
        play = input('Would you like to run this program again? ') 
      else:
        print('It took', flips, 'flips.')
        play = input('Would you like to run this program again? ') 
    else: #if possible is false
      print("IMPOSSIBLE.") #printing that the burgers can't be flipped with the flipper the size inputted in 'flipper'
      play = input("Would you like to run this program again? ") 
    if play not in ['Yes', 'yes', 'Y', 'y']: 
      exit()
```

Many thanks for your help as I am fairly new to programming.

James

Comment: What is that 0 right next to `if remainder != 0:` does not look right.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't meant to be there! It was a mistake. James

Comment: It doesn't work if it is 4 where is actually can with BBAABB with the first flip being AABBBB and the second making it AAAAAA. I have checked and it does work with 2 not 4. Thanks.

Comment: My bad, saw 2 and not 4, with 4 it does not work since your condition for impossible is too basic, it considers only flipping B's into A's

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new to programming and I'm not really sure how to make the A's flip to B's as well with my code, which if I can do that I think it will solve the problem. James

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is that you have to get the flipping logic to also flip A's to B's like BBAABB where it can be done with 2 as you just have to convert the B's to A's so it will be AAAAAA but when you enter 4 you will have to flip the A's into B's which currently is not included in your program.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to look for a 'B', which has to be flipped, and then see if you have enough pancakes following the first 'B' to flip per the flipper size.  If you can, you do the flip and increase the flip count.  You just keep repeating this until you can't do a full flip starting with a 'B', at which point you can't get to all 'A's.  But if whenever you can find a 'B', you can flip 'flipper' pancakes, you'll end up being able to get to all 'A's:

```
def flip(str, pos, count):
    r = str[:pos]
    for i in range(pos, pos + count):
        r += 'A' if str[i] == 'B' else 'B'
    r += str[pos + count:]
    return r

while True:
    pancakes = input('Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): ')
    flipper = int(input('How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? '))

    flips, possible = 0, True
    while True:
        try:
            i = pancakes.index('B')
        except ValueError:
            # no 'B's, so we did it!
            break
        if (i > len(pancakes) - flipper):
            # not enough pancakes left to flip starting with a 'B', so we can't do it.
            possible = False
            break
        else:
            # Can do a flip, starting with a 'B', so do it
            pancakes = flip(pancakes, i, flipper)
            flips += 1

    if possible:
        if flips == 1:
            print('It took 1 flip.')  # print out how many flips it took
        else:
            print('It took', flips, 'flips.')
    else:  # if possible is false
        print("IMPOSSIBLE.")  # printing that the burgers can't be flipped with the flipper the size inputted in 'flipper'
    play = input("Would you like to run this program again? ")
    if play not in ['Yes', 'yes', 'Y', 'y']:
        exit()
```

Result:

```
Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): BBAABB
How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? 4
It took 2 flips.
Would you like to run this program again? y
Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): ABBAABBAAA
How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? 4
It took 2 flips.
Would you like to run this program again? y
Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): AAAA
How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? 2
It took 0 flips.
Would you like to run this program again? y
Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): BBBB
How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? 2
It took 2 flips.
Would you like to run this program again? y
Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): BBBB
How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? 4
It took 1 flip.
Would you like to run this program again? y
Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): ABBB
How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? 2
IMPOSSIBLE.
Would you like to run this program again? y
Enter the row of the pancakes (A/B): ABBB
How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? 4
IMPOSSIBLE.
Would you like to run this program again? n

Process finished with exit code 0
```